# Vectorize operation of tensors instead of using for-loop inside keras custom loss function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm writing a custom loss function, which uses as penalty matrix to compute the loss. The `y_true` and `y_pred` values are the indices of the matrix penalty matrix `A`:

```
def score(y_true, y_pred):
    S = 0.0
    for i in range(0, y_true.shape[0]):
      S -= A[y_true[i], y_pred[i]]
    return S/y_true.shape[0]
```

Since the for loop does not give the best performance, I was wondering how could I do the following snippet of code without it.

```
S -= A[y_true[i], y_pred[i]]
```

Comment: As far as I remember, you need at least one `for` loop to compute the loss function. Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example? Include how one would run `score`, with all necessary variables defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the following would work for you, if `y_true` contains your row indices and `y_pred` contains your column indices

```
S = -sum(A[y_true,y_pred])
```

Comment: This does work and it is close to what I am looking for, although I'm actually looking for the Tensor way of doing it.

Comment: @joão What do you mean by Tensor? Tensorflow?

Comment: Instead of using a numpy array, using a Tensor object, but don't worry I already figured it out.